# Pinescript plotting and deleting lines using arrays

Tags: pine-script

The code below should plot horizontal lines when the market makes new M15 highs or lows. And if the high or low is broken, delete the line.

```
m15Hoch = ta.valuewhen(m15High2, high15[1], 0)
m15Tief = ta.valuewhen(m15Low2, low15[1], 0)
var h = array.new_line()
array.push(h, line.new(m15Hoch_bar_index, m15Hoch, m15Hoch_bar_index + 1, m15Hoch, extend = extend.right, color = color.blue))

if ta.crossover(high, m15Hoch)
    ln = array.pop(h)
    line.delete(ln)
```